# Why this question is ok and this is not?

Tags: discussion

### [What are the health benefits of vegetarianism?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/23/115)

- score of +5/-1
- open and alive

### [What are the health benefits of raw veganism?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/527/115)

- 0 score
- on-hold for being "too broad"

Please help me to understand which is the difference between the two questions because I can't see any.

Answer (score 6):

Questions like these are *very* broad by definition. There's nothing *inherently* wrong with the question itself, but this is more a talking point into a much *larger* discussion or debate than something that can be definitively "answered" in what we typically call *Q&A.*

Users can guess at what type of information will help you specifically, but without a specific problem statement, users will tend to post random bits of information and anecdotes that *touch* on the subject — and maybe you can pick through the answers later and find something useful, relevant, or entertaining…

except that isn't the purpose of creating a Stack Exchange site.

Stack Exchange is supposed to be a collection of solutions to the problems users actually face in this space every day. We accomplish that through a unit of information we call Q&A. The best, most "correct answer" on that subject is supposed to rise to the top — complete, definitive, and at least somewhat rankably answerable as "most correct".

Long story short, Stack Exchange is supposed to be a Q&A and not a discussion forum. The problem with "let's talk about this big subject in one post" is that folks will see fit to closing much more useful, detailed questions as a duplicate of this one later. Maybe that doesn't happen, but that *IS* how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Ok thank you! Now it's way more understandable to me.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I disagree with the close and thus have voted to reopen.

What happened is Robert, being an employee, "hammered" it closed (i.e. normally 5 votes are needed, his counts for all 5 and he single-handedly closed it).

His thinking was most likely that "big list" questions aren't allowed, and that your question was one. I disagree, and as we've seen 'what are the health benefits' questions can be okay.

Comment: The question is now open.